# Completing a command like another command in bash

Tags: autocomplete

Let's say I'm creating a wrapper for the Unix program `wget` called `wget-hip`. I want `wget-hip` to get the same shell completion rule as `wget` because they both happen to have the same command-line options.

So if wget has this completion rule:

```
complete -F _wget wget
```

or:

```
complete -C _wget wget
```

then I want:

```
complete -F _wget wget-hip
```

or:

```
complete -C _wget wget-hip
```

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The `-p` option might be of use. From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins):

> If the `-p` option is supplied, or if no options are supplied, existing
>   completion specifications are printed in a way that allows them to be
>   reused as input.

So, perhaps:

```
$(complete -p wget)-hip
```

Comment: Two issues: 1) the output of "complete -p" is not readily usable; 2) the existence of "on-demand" completion by completion loader ("complete -D") complicates things, because we must evaluate this "complete -D" if we want to search for completion more exhaustively.

Comment: @GerryLufwansa not usable how? Also, edit clarifications into your question, please

Comment: The output of `complete -p wget` is currently `bash: complete: wget: no completion specification` (bash 5.0.3(1)-release, and there is indeed valid completion for wget).